# In need of some PHP/server help on my mac (Snow leopard)

Tags: php, osx-snow-leopard

I'm learning php and mySQL for the first time (using Welling/Thomson) and I'm using my mac as the server. In doing so I'm turning on web sharing and accessing it through something like `http://192.168.0.103/~myname/` or `localhost/~myname/`. I'm able to run basic PHP scripts. I set up everything using this [guide](http://maestric.com/doc/mac/apache_php_mysql_snow_leopard). I have each example divided into the chapters: to get to the chapter 1 projects I go through `localhost/~myname/book/Chapter02/example.html` in my browser. These files are actually stored in `/Users/myname/Sites/book/Chapter02/example.html`

I'm attempting to do file openings and get the following error:

`Warning: fopen(/Library/WebServer/Documents/../orders/orders.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/myname/Sites/book/Chapter02/processorder.php on line 72`

I first thought that it was because the directory and the fopen were different, so instead of storing my files in `localhost/~myname/`, I tried `localhost/public_html/` Storing them there is actually `/Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/` on my computer. I still get the error:

`Warning: fopen(/Library/WebServer/Documents/../orders/orders.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/Chapter02/processorder.php on line 72`

Then I looked it up online and saw that it had to do with permissions. I created a directory in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/Chapter02/` called "orders" with read & write permissions from everyone through the terminal (done with chmod), but still I get the same error. I'm not sure where the problem is. If it is my server set-up, where are the files? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the php script if you think it will help http://pastebin.com/14gpim8e

I'm trying to be as clear as I can, but I'm sure this will need some clarification so feel free to ask if you need any more information.

Comment: When you do ls -la in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/Chapter02/` what do you get? Also, what do you get when you do that in `/Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/Chapter02/orders`?

Comment: Try $fp = fopen(realpath($DOCUMENT_ROOT.'/../orders/orders.txt'), 'ab');

Comment: @NathanielFord This is what I get

`drwxrwxrwx@ 7 myname  admin   238 Jul  3 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 myname  admin   136 Jul  3 12:00 ..
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 myname  admin  6148 Jul  3 12:00 .DS_Store
-rwxrw-rw-@ 1 myname  admin   855 Jul  3 09:10 orderform.html
drwxrwxrwx  2 myname  admin    68 Jul  3 12:02 orders
-rwxrw-rw-@ 1 myname  admin  1950 Jul  3 09:38 processorder.php
-rwxrw-rw-@ 1 myname  admin   707 Jul  7  2008 vieworders.php`

Sorry about bad formatting.

Comment: @madflow I'm trying but I'm getting an Error 500. Do you know how I should format it? Currently I have it as `$fp = fopen(Volumes/Macintosh HD/Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/Chapter02/orders("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/../orders/orders.txt")), 'ab');`

Comment: I meant line 72 in the pastebin... A "500" is probably the Apache Webserver error code.

Comment: @madflow Okay, so just replace that whole thing with the line you gave me. When I did that I got a new error "Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in /Library/WebServer/Documents/public_html/Chapter02/processorder.php on line 72"

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.

The problem came in 2 ways:

1. finding where the file was supposed to be, and
2. permissions.

In this case, it needed read/write permissions from everybody, and it needed to be in the /WebServer/ directory and no lower (as I had been doing in every single directory but the WebServer one. Seems kind of dumb now that I couldn't get it). Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Based on your output, I bet that it's not that it's 'read/write' from everyone, but that the file's groups aren't configured correctly. Do you know what your webserver runs as? apache? admin? myname? Something else?

Comment: @NathanielFord I believe it is Apache.

Comment: In that case, you need to `chown apache` the files you want apache to own, or `chown myuser:apache` the files you want apache to have in it's group. That way you don't need to make all your files world-readable and world-writable.